# Text to Hex PHP Losing Characters

Tags: php, bash, exec

i have the below code and i at that point where google and searching has not helped

```
exec("echo -n '$cmd' | xxd -ps | sed -e ':a' -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\|^\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\\x\2/;ta' | sed 's|[\\x,]||g' | xargs echo -n | tr -d ' '", $cmdhex);
```

i am executing that via PHP using

```
./test.php 'help1234'
```

output is `6c34`

NOW that i know is wrong hex value. IF i run the following

just in cash i get this

```
echo -n 'help1234' | xxd -ps | sed -e ':a' -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\|^\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\\x\2/;ta' | sed 's|[\\x,]||g' | xargs echo -n | tr -d ' '
```

my output is

```
68656c7031323334
```

WHICH is correct. so my question is, why is it that i am getting the wrong output when using `exec` via `php`?

thanks!

Comment: In php you'll need to escape the backslash characters.

Comment: Thank you, added the extra \'s and it worked. I am not an expert in reg. exp's

Comment: my last question would be... how come when sending this    `exec("echo -ne '060e'.$hex.$cmdoutput | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3");`   in command vs php it works in command it doesnt work in php?

Comment: Possibly because $1 gets replaced by an empty string.

Comment: how can i go around that? @Maerlyn

Comment: @Maerlyn Sorry to bug you, im still a bit stomped on this =|

Comment: Escaping the dollar sign should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes in `exec("...")` calculate one level of your backslash chars, so the regular expresion becomes different/corrupted.

Add a second level of backslashes or use single-quotes and backslash them in the `exec` parameter string.

Comment: Can you help me with the above? @TE KO ? It seems the $1 is getting chopped off and still cannot seem to figure this out